# Join in SQL Server with rows below it

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find a way to join the rows of a table with rows below it. Not sure if this is even a thing but thought I'd ask.

```
Table A
Name StartDate EndDate  
A    01/01/15  01/12/2015
B    31/01/15  01/03/2015
C    01/04/15  01/08/2015
D    21/07/15  01/05/2015
```

I want to get the people who overlap in dates. From the example, A overlaps with B, C and D then I require AB, AC and AD but also want to ignore BA, CA, and DA.

```
So the output from Table A should be:
A B
A C
A D
B D
C D
```

For now, I am joining the table to itself but cannot get rid of duplicates i.e. I've got both AB and BA in my result. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Just add an extra condition to the comparison:

```
select a.name, a2.name
from a a join
     a a2
     on a.startdate <= a2.enddate and
        a.enddate >= a2.startdate and
        a.name < a2.name;
```

Two date ranges overlap when the first starts before the second ends, and the first ends after the second starts.

Note:  depending on whether or not the end dates are inclusive, you might want strict inequalities for the comparisons.

Comment: Nice and neat!  Good catch to also add the comparison on name with "<".

Comment: Hi! a.name < a2.name doe snot work since the IDs are numbers and type int instead of text.

Comment: I added a.userId <> a2.userID but then this does not help in removing the duplicates and I end up getting almost twice the amount of the rows required.

Comment: @vsg . . . `<` works for character strings.  Use that.